# Django base64 TypeError __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)

Tags: python-3.x, django, oracle, base64

i got this error: TypeError at /productos/productos/
**str** returned non-string (type bytes) i think is a problem from convert from base64bits to str, but i dont know how to fix it, im using *Procedures* on oracle but its dont seem to be an issue.

Im ussing django 3.1, oracle database 18c. all works perfectly since i implement the image blob, its a requeriment so i have to use it.

At line 56: **return render(request, "productos/productos.html", data)**

**views.py**

```
def product(request):
data = {
    'product':()
}

if request.method == 'POST':
    id_producto = request.POST.get('id_producto')
    nombre = request.POST.get('nombre')
    tipo = request.POST.get('tipo')
    descripcion = request.POST.get('descripcion')
    stock = request.POST.get('stock')
    precio = request.POST.get('precio')
    catalogo = request.POST.get('catalogo')
    imagen = request.FILES['imagen'].read()
   

    salida = agregar_producto(id_producto,nombre,tipo,descripcion,stock,precio,catalogo,imagen)
    if salida == 1:
        data['mensaje'] = 'added sucessfully'
        data['productos'] = product_list()
    else:
        data['mensaje'] = 'cannot save'

return render(request, "productos/productos.html", data)


def product_list():
django_cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor = django_cursor.connection.cursor()
out_cur = django_cursor.connection.cursor()

cursor.callproc("sp_product_list", [out_cur])

row = []
for row in out_cur:
    data = {
        'data':row,
        'imagen':str(base64.b64encode(row[7].read()), 'utf-8')
    }

    lista.append(data)

return row
```

**productos.html** Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\galli\desarrollo-web-36sk8mafia\trisix\plantillas\plantilla.html, error at line 0

**str** returned non-string (type bytes)

```
{% extends "plantilla.html" %}
{% load static %}
<title>{% block title %}Productos {% endblock %}</title>

{% block content %}

            <p><h1>CRUD Productos</h1></p>
            <br>
            <p><h2>Agregar Producto</h2>
            </p>

            <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="">Id_producto</label>
                <input type="number" name="id_producto">
                <br>
                <label for="">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre">
                <br>
                <label for="">Tipo</label>
                <input type="text" name="tipo">
                <br>
                <label for="">Descripcion</label>
                <input type="text" name="descripcion">
                <br>
                <label for="">Stock</label>
                <input type="number" name="stock">
                <br>
                <label for="">Precio</label>
                <input type="number" name="precio">
                <br>
                <label for="">Catalogo</label>
                <input type="number" name="catalogo">
                <br>
                <label for="">Imagen</label>
                <input type="file" name="imagen">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar">
            </form>

            {{mensaje}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Id_producto</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Descripcion</th>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Catalogo</th>
            
        </tr>
        {% for p in productos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ p.data.1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.2 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.3 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.4 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.5 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.6 }}</td>
                <td>{{ p.data.7 }}</td>
                <td> 
                    {% if p.imagen %}
                    <img src="data:imagen/png;base64, {{p.imagen}}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>      
    
  {% endblock %}
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the local vars:

```
    data    
{'productos': [{'data': (1,
                     '1',
                     '1',
                     '1',
                     1,
                     1,
                     1,
                     <cx_Oracle.LOB object at 0x0000023EEFC771E0>),
            'imagen': BUNCH OF BINARIES CHARACTERS.
            <trimmed 85961 bytes string>
            request 
            <WSGIRequest: GET '/productos/productos/'>
```

**FULL TRACEBACK**

```
                Environment:


            Request Method: GET
            Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/productos/productos/

            Django Version: 3.1.2
            Python Version: 3.8.5
            Installed Applications:
            ['django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'mtv.apps.MtvConfig']
            Installed Middleware:
            ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


            Template error:
            In template C:\Users\galli\desarrollo-web-36sk8mafia\trisix\plantillas\plantilla.html, error at line 0
            __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
            1 : {% load static %}
            2 : <!doctype html>
            3 : <html lang="en">
            4 :   <head>
            5 :     <!-- Required meta tags -->
            6 :     <meta charset="utf-8">
            7 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            8 :     
            9 :     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
            10 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
            File "C:\Users\galli\desarrollo-web-36sk8mafia\trisix\views.py", line 55, in productos
                return render(request, "productos/productos.html", data)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
                content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
                return template.render(context, request)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
                return self.template.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
                return self._render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
                return self.nodelist.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
                return self.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
                return compiled_parent._render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
                return self.nodelist.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
                return self.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
                return self.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 211, in render
                nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
                return self.render(context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 994, in render
                return render_value_in_context(output, context)
            File "G:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Django\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 973, in render_value_in_context
                value = str(value)

            Exception Type: TypeError at /productos/productos/
            Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type bytes)
```

Comment: What's on line 56?

Comment: At line 56: return render(request, "productos/productos.html", data)

Comment: Edited: added full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

plantilla.html is in utf-8, right? although this doesn't seem to be the error
can you check `type(str(base64.b64encode(row[7].read()), 'utf-8'))` ?
Instead of this

```html
{% if p.imagen %}
<img src="data:imagen/png;base64, {{p.imagen}}" alt="" width="100" height="100">
{% endif %}
```

do this

```html
{% if p.imagen %}{{p.imagen}}{% endif %}
```

And instead of this:

```py
'imagen':str(base64.b64encode(row[7].read()), 'utf-8')
```

do this

```py
'imagen':str(type(str(base64.b64encode(row[7].read()), 'utf-8')))
```

What does it say? `str` ?

Comment: doesnt work, same error. and plantilla.html its utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Finally i gave up with this method, but i think the problem are the
def **str**(self):
return self.id_producto

you have to comment all the def on your models to get rid of this.